# CKEditor 4 hyperlink style

Tags: ckeditor

I am trying to style hyperlinks in CKEditor.
from `<a data-cke-saved-href="..." href="...">Link</a>` to `<a data-cke-saved-href="..." href="..." style="color:[whatever was chosen with button]; text-decoration: inherit">Link</a>`

Seems simple, but I cannot figure it out.

To style elements with the color button of CKeditor (v.4), I can of course add this to config:

```
colorButton_foreStyle: {
  element: 'a',
  styles: { color: '#(color)', 'text-decoration': 'none' },
}
```

This will work for hyperlinks, but then no other tags will be stylable (if not clear why, please ask)

Is there another configuration for hyperlinks I am missing? How would you go about achieving this? I need the style to be inlined and controlled by the color button since this is for an Email templating tool.

Thanks for your advise!

Answer (score 1):

When you style a link with color button, you get code like:

```
<a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Armstrong" title="Neil Armstrong"><span style="color:#d35400">Neil Armstrong</span></a>
```

As you can see link doesn't get styled but only text inside it. This is being done by design - https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/colorbutton/plugin.js#L226-L233. From what I have further checked, the only way to style the link is through the `Advanced Tab` in `Link` dialog.

Comment: Didn't know about Advanced Tab. Not sure why it doesn't show by default. Although I ended up just adding the Source plugin and then everything is possible :)

Comment: If you look at the https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addons/search/plugins/advanced%20tab you will notice that Advanced Tab for Dialogs is by default only available for full preset. If you are using standard or basic then this plugins won't be available by default and you either need to add it manually or use online builder to do that - https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder. The advantage of online builder is that once you add the plugin it will also add all the necessary required dependencies.

Comment: Small Note - please always check what plugin is doing and whether it is compatible with the latest editor version. While there are many third-party as well as CKSource core plugins which are maintained and tested against every new release, there are also plugins which may conflict with other plugins or which got created once but author is not interested in maintaining them anymore and they may not be necessarily compatible with the latest CKEditor version (please always visit plugin website to verify that and check its raiting as well as comments under the plugin).

Comment: Noted. Thanks. A quick not so related question for you, if you know CKeditor well. Do you know any "merge fields" plugin for it?

Comment: Please describe in more detail what exactly you want to merge with this plugin? How should it work?

Comment: I need to drop in database field values per client. Like hello [FIRST NAME], you have [NUMBER OF DRINKS] waiting for you. I need tree structure select (hopefully) to select merge fields. Like Basic > Name, Basic > Email, Advanced > Number of Drinks, Advanced > Favorite Drink, etc. Hope it makes sense

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I have missed your comment. Unfortunately I don't know any such ready to use plugin in CKEditor. You could try searching the add-ons repository but I personally don't recall anything what you have described - https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addons/plugins/all.